# GROUP BY month on DATETIME field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query in mysql:

```
SELECT title, 
       added_on 
FROM   title
```

The results looks like this:

```
Somos Tão Jovens                        2013-10-10 16:54:10
Moulin Rouge - Amor em Vermelho         2013-10-10 16:55:03
Rocky Horror Picture Show (Legendado)   2013-10-10 16:58:30
The X-Files: I Want to Believe          2013-10-10 22:39:11
```

I would like to get the count for the titles in each month, so the result would look like this:

```
Count               Month
42                  2013-10-01
20                  3013-09-01
```

The closest I can think of to get this is:

```
SELECT Count(*), 
       Date(timestamp) 
FROM   title 
GROUP  BY Date(timestamp)
```

But this is only grouping by the day, and not the month. How would I group by the month here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
select count(*), DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m-01")
from title
group by DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m-01")
```

Please, note that `MONTH()` can't differentiate '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-01' as follows.

```
mysql> SELECT MONTH('2013-01-01'), MONTH('2014-01-01');
+---------------------+---------------------+
| MONTH('2013-01-01') | MONTH('2014-01-01') |
+---------------------+---------------------+
|                   1 |                   1 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: If you name the `DATE_FORMAT` select then you don't have to repeat it in the `group by` part e.g. `SELECT count(*), DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m-01") AS month FROM title GROUP BY month`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Count(*), 
       Date(timestamp) 
FROM   title 
GROUP  BY Month(timestamp)
```

Edit: And obviously if it matters to display the 1st day of the month in the results, you do the `DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m-01")` thing mentioned in some other answers :)

Comment: If datetime values span the year(s) boundaries this will produce wrong results

Comment: He only asks for it to be grouped by month, so "wrong results" might as well be exactly what he is looking for :) Otherwise GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp) will do the trick to keep years seperated.

Answer (score 4):

The best bet is to group it by YEAR and then by MONTH. See below

```
SELECT Count(*), Date(timestamp) FROM title GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), Month(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*), date(timestamp) from title group by MONTHNAME(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
       count(*) as Count,
       MONTH(timestamp)+"-"+YEAR(timestamp) as Month 
from 
       title 
GROUP BY 
        MONTH(tumestamp);
```

Comment: Well it shall not be `date(timestamp)` in select clause!

Comment: Exactly my question is