# Group query for months

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this table.

```
+------------------------+--------------------+-----+
| id                     |mydate              |value|| 
+------------------------+------+-----+-------------+
| 1                      |2018-06-18 18:34:09 |50   | 
| 2                      |2018-06-18 12:34:09 |50   |
| 3                      |2018-08-18 13:34:09 |10   |
| 4                      |2018-08-18 14:34:09 |10   |
| 5                      |2018-09-18 16:34:09 |20   |
| 6                      |2018-09-18 17:34:09 |10   |
+------------------------+--------------------+-----+
```

I would like a Query to get something similar 
Group for months

I would like a consultation to achieve this

```
|mydate   |value|
+---------------+    
June      |100  |
August    |20   |
September |30   |
```

**in case it is not possible with MySQL. (It could be in PHP)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP BY month on DATETIME field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963503/group-by-month-on-datetime-field)

Comment: @GuillaumeBoudreau If you feel that it's a possible duplicate, it's best to "flag" it as one instead of typing it out as a comment. When it gets flagged, it shows up somewhere that others may pickup on voting to close as such also. Also, if I or someone else who can hammer it with it in one go, then that too will show your name on it, rather than just the person who hammered it. Just thought I'd let you know how voting to close works. Why I think you did that would probably be that you can't "vote" to close as a duplicate. Right you are, *but* you can "flag" as duplicate though :-) *Cheers*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That is what I did (use `flag`); I didn't type that message; I guess SO implementation of the 'flag' feature depends on how much reputations the user has, and in my case, selecting a duplicate in the `flag` UI created a comment for me.

Comment: @GuillaumeBoudreau Ok thanks. I think there might be a bug happening here, since the flag *should* have shown a "1" under the "close" option. I've been Googling this and found these https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295337/231583 - 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366039/1415724 - Hard to say what's going on. Maybe it's normal but I've always seen a "1" under the "close" button under a question when it does get flagged. Thanks for getting back to me (merci). Edit: Now there is a "1" showing; odd.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295344/391510

Comment: @GuillaumeBoudreau I did see that, did you see [the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295337/how-to-post-a-possible-duplicate-of-question-comment/295344#comment958196_295344) under it also? That's why I am starting to question the way flagging works for members whose rep is below 3000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sum`, `group by`, and `MONTHNAME` to get the result you need.

```
select sum(value), MONTHNAME(mydate) as month 
from test 
group by month
```

<s>If you require the text version of the months you could swap that in PHP.</s>

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26b8fb/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(mydate) as month, SUM(value) as value FROM myTable GROUP BY month
```