# Count entries per month and group

Tags: mysql

I have a table with entries and a time/date stamp. For example:

```
1   2014-03-14 12:34:49
2   2014-03-14 12:34:49
3   2014-03-14 12:34:49
4   2014-03-25 09:59:15
5   2014-03-25 09:59:15
etc.....
```

I want to count the number of entries per month

I have tried this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS entries, DATE(timestmp) as date 
FROM remlog 
GROUP BY DATE(timestmp)
```

Comment: Please share your code. [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP BY month on DATETIME field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963503/group-by-month-on-datetime-field)

Answer (score 0):

use `month()`

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS entries, month(timestmp) as date 
    FROM remlog 
    GROUP BY month(timestmp)
```